# What is the usage of the 'name' attribute in H1..H6 tags?

Tags: html

As far as I understand, the `id` attribute is used as a unique identifier for some tag in the entire document, while `name` is used as an identifier (not necessarily unique in the document) that is sent with some data to the server.

However, using the element inspector in pages from the MDN (take [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) as an example), I noticed that all the article's `h1`..`h6` tags that are present in the navigation tree have `name` attributes, and that they are identical to their respective tag's `id`s. In this case, what is the usage of such attributes? Are they used to build the navigation tree?

Comment: Back in the old days browsers would use the name attribute of tags to identify locations on the page when the URL ended with a `#`. As time moved on we eventually moved to the idea of `id` being used instead, but for those still running old browsers many people maintain the old name attributes and ID attributes to the same values just to ensure no-one get's a degraded experience.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a valid attribute for H* elements (http://validator.w3.org/check confirms it). However, those elements who have a `name` attribute (like `img`) have this added to the description in the HTML spec: *"Note. This attribute has been included for backwards compatibility. Applications should use the id attribute to identify elements."*

Comment: @FelixKling, your note applies to the `name` attribute in *some* elements, like `img` and `a`, but not e.g. `input` (where `name` is valid and indispensable).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Yep, I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute is allowed in various elements and has partly different meanings in them. On the page linked to in the question, it is used in heading elements, e.g.

```
<h2 id="JavaScript_Review" name="JavaScript_Review">JavaScript review</h2>
```

Such usage is not valid in any HTML version, and the `name` attribute has no effect in such elements. The construct is probably generated by some authoring software that has been coded or configured oddly.

To be exact, the attribute (like unknown attributes in general) is not completely ignored. It is stored in the DOM, in the `attributes` object of the element node (but not as `name` property of the node, as it would be if it were a defined attribute). This means that it *could* be used in scripting and in styling.

Comment: So it's basically a mistake? I wouldn't be bothered if it was another website, but it's just odd (although obviously not impossible) that a learning center of this kind has such (not so subtle) thing.

Comment: @EdJr, if you check the page with http://validator.w3.org you will see other markup errors too (though not as odd as this).

Answer (score 5):

Most likely it's used for bookmark anchors to jump to a specific part of the page. In ye olden days, you would use the name attribute to target the element, today however you use the ID. So it's probably just a holdover for backwards compatibility.

If you check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Clicking_and_focus, you'll see the explanation:

> **name** (HTML 4 only, Obsolete since HTML5) This attribute is required in
>   an anchor defining a target location within a page. A value for name
>   is similar to a value for the id core attribute and should be an
>   alphanumeric identifier unique to the document. **Under the HTML 4.01
>   specification, id and name both can be used with the `<a>` element as
>   long as they have identical values. Usage note: This attribute is
>   obsolete in HTML5, use global attribute id instead.**

Comment: The answer addresses the issue of using `name` in `a` elements, but the question is about heading elements like `h2`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - The user is asking why the headings have name attributes. I explained how they were used as bookmark/named anchors. Where's the confusion?

Comment: They were never used that way; `name` attributes e.g. in `h2` elements do not create anchors of any kind.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - They absolutely did. You could jump to the heading by giving a name and referencing it via a link.

Comment: Can you cite a browser that ever recognized the attribute in `<h2 name="foo">text</h2>`?

Comment: Actually yes, IE6 & 7 did it in my VM. There may be more, I just happened to have those open.

Comment: I just tested on IE 6, and it did not recognize it. No HTML spec ever defined `name` for `h2`. The quoted text in the answer deals with the `a` element, not `h2`.